# Consider the relation R given by divisibility on positive integers that is xRy <-> x|y

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, relations

Consider the relation R given by divisibility on positive integers that is xRy <-> x|y
Is this relation reflexive? symmetric? anti-symmetric? transitive??

I understand it is reflexive and transitive but i got a little confuse between symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Because the solution i have for anti-symmetric mention is True 
given that x|y = 1 and y|x = 1, hence x = y having the same value. so i was wondering if i use the argument for anti-symmetric on symmetric, won't is make the whole thing symmetric too?

Answer (score 1):

Working straight from the definition on wikipedia, is suffices to show that if $a|b$ and $b|a$, then $a=b$. Just expand these hypotheses out as $a=mb$ and $b=na$  for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and notice that both $n=m=1$. Assuming you are working with $\mathbb{N}$. This shows your relation is anti-symmetric.

Let's show it's not symmetric just because we can. Notice that $5|10$ but $10\not|5$, so it's not true in general that $aRb$ implies $bRa$ for each $a$ and $b$.

Comment: thank jack, but i was wondering if i use 10|10 or 5|5 to prove the symmetric is this consider a valid prove or is not?

Comment: it might seem like that, but unfortunately no. Both those cases all under the reflexive property, since $a=b$. When we want to talk about symmetry or anti-symmetry we assume that $a\neq b$.

Comment: ok, if that the case for anti-symmetric in order for a = b, example 5 = (1) * 5, won't that make it a = b or because (1) * 5 is consider different because of the expression??

Comment: Yes, so the logic is: Given $a\neq b$, then $aRb=bRa$ implies $R$ is symmetric. If $R$ is anti-symmetric, then given $aRb=bRa$ we know that $a=b$.

Comment: oh.. ok.. thank for help...

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't quite understand what you are saying. The example $5=1\times 5$ is not an example that $R$ is symmetric, but rather that $R$ is reflexive. Hope some of this helps :D

Comment: ok, because you mention that for comparing symmetric and anti-symmetric we cannot assume a≠b, so for that i understand for symmetric part. 

but for anti-symmetric it mean aRb and bRa mean
a = b. so for my previous post, anti-symmetric mean 
a = mb and b = na does that imply we using the reflexive property a = b or it is not because the expression 
a = b ≠ a = mb even thought the result is the same?

Comment: Ah. I think I see the confusion. For symmetric you assume $a\neq b$ and proceed. For anti-symmetric you assume $a\neq b$ and show $aRb$ implies $bRa$ is not true, which is equivalent to showing that if $aRb$ implies $bRa$, then $a=b$. The wikipedia article summarizes this too.

Comment: ok... hahah... thank for your help...

Comment: @JackDavies "When we want to talk about symmetry or anti-symmetry we assume that $a\neq b$" Actually, we shouldn't. We assume that $a$ and $b$ are _arbitrary_, which means that they might or might not be equal. Intuitively, of course, this works like assuming that they _may_ be different (until possibly proved otherwise!), but if we make this intuition into the stronger assumption that they _be_ different, then we're led to unnecessary logical detours which obscure rather than explain things: for example, why is the equality relation "$aRb$ iff $a = b$" symmetric? why is it antisymmetric?...

Comment: Yes I agree @Basil. I thought the distinction between reflexive and symmetric needed to be made in this case given the question. I do agree with you though!